# c++ stack functions and error handleing

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
      void pop()
      {
           //create new temp node
           struct PersonNode *temp;
           //if stack is empty
           if(top==NULL)
           {
               cout<<"nThe stack is empty!!!"; // show message
           }
           temp=top; // store the top at temp
           top=top->next; // make the top previous to current top
           delete temp; // delete the temp (current top)
      }
```

this is the code i'm using to pop out of stack, which works except when the stack is empty and i try to pop in it crashes, i think its due to this line 
top = top->next;

Comment: What's the NULL-check there for if you still do the same things?

Comment: You don't need the extra `struct` in `struct PersonNode *temp;`, and that should be moved down to where you actually assign it (or initialized to `nullptr`).

Comment: Also, you need an `else` there (you *don't* make a change if the stack is empty).

Comment: crasgmstr this works

Comment: `//create new temp node
           struct PersonNode *temp;` Are you actually sure this does what's stated in the comment??

Comment: this has been solved by putting temp=top...delete temp inside else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code cleaned up a little (only declare `temp` where needed and initialize immediately, and guard against working on an empty stack with an `else` clause).

```
void pop()
{
    //if stack is empty, show message and stop
    if(!top)
    {
        cout<<"nThe stack is empty!!!";
    }
    else //else stack is not empty, pop
    {
       PersonNode *temp = top;
       top = top->next;
       delete temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
top=top->next;
```

will fail if `top` is `NULL`, so you should simply return without executing the rest of the statements in your function:

```
 if(top==NULL) {
     cout<<"nThe stack is empty!!!"; // show message
     return; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
 }
```

Comment: without that code the function no longer pops at all
            temp=top; // store the top at temp
           top=top->next; // make the top previous to current top
           delete temp; // delete the temp (current top)

Comment: @Danny Well, please post a [MCVE]. That might help to diagnose your real problem.

Comment: _"without that code the function no longer pops at all `temp=top`; "_ That assignment isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You should return when the `top` is `NULL`

```
   if(top==NULL)
   {
       cout<<"nThe stack is empty!!!"; // show message
       return;//You Should return from here
   }
```

Hope This Helps.